# How to assign tasks to workers while optimizing workload and minimizing travel distance?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, modeling

Does anyone know of any good algorithms for solving the following problem? I have maintenance workers located in about 300 locations in a given area. In the same area, there are about 40 000 maintenance tasks that need to be done in a month. Is there a way to optimize the assignment of these tasks to the workers in a way that workload is optimized (no one is overworked and no one is without work) while travel distances are minimized?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there's a silver bullet. I guess there are more constraints than you have given. Has every worker the same skills and can do every job? How are jobs prioritized? Do you need special equipment or spare parts for certain jobs? What should happen when you can't stick to a plan, because somebody is ill or a task takes longer than expected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, every task can be done by any worker, and everyone has the necessary equipment. Right now, these are the only constraints that we are taking into account. Thanks a lot for trying to help!

Comment: Depending on your other constraints this might be a variation of the [Vehicle Routing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem), [Spatial Crowdsourcing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03149.pdf) or [Job Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling).